# Owncloud download fail behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have raspberry pi with nginx as reverse proxy and another machine with owncloud on nginx too.

I can connect and browse in the pages but when I try to download a file that weight more than about 50mo, the download start a bit and fails.

I know the problem come from the reverse proxy, because if I access owncloud directly (locally), downloads work.

owncloud vhost :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name cloud.spooky4672.me;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name cloud.spooky4672.me;

    #SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cloud/cloud.spooky4672_chain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cloud/key.pem;

    #LOGS
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/owncloud-error.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://local_ip;
    }
}
```

proxy.conf

```
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffer_size   16k;
    proxy_buffers       32   16k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
```

Comment: Maybe try some real hardware instead of the RasPi.

Comment: So we really can find troll everywhere :)

Comment: Not trolling. You asked your question on a site for professional systems administrators, so expect to get professional-level advice. If I were in your shoes, removing the RasPi would be the first thing I'd try.

Comment: This is just a setup for me and friends, and the pi is clearly not the problem

Comment: Well, you haven't provided any evidence to show that.

Comment: I have others service behind the nginx proxy, like phpbb, and it work great

Comment: But I bet you aren't performing large downloads from any of those.

Comment: can you monitor ram/swap usage during the download? results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered on StackOverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932569/can-not-upload-big-files-with-nginx-reverse-proxyssl-negotiation-and-tomcat

`client_max_body_size 1000m;`

Also check out
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size

and try `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0`

Comment: It works, but the download stay a very long time at 0ko/s, weird ...

Comment: Thanks!   It was proxy_max_temp_file_size that worked for me to fix freezing large downloads.